# How to conditionally change values of keys of an object in an object array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following object and it's keys in the array named `objectArray` of `clothesTypes[]`.

```
const objectArray: clothesTypes[] = [
  {
    trousers: 90,
    'skirts and jackets': 47,
    scarfs: 100,
  },
]
```

Then I have another array of type `userData[]`, which is being updated (when a user buys cloth).

```
const userArray: userData[] = [
  {
    name: 'David',
    clothType: 'trousers',
    price: 45,
  },
  {
    name: 'Joanna',
    clothType: 'scarfs',
    price: 5,
  },
  {
    name: 'Gillian',
    clothType: 'trousers',
    price: 35,
  },
]
```

What I need to do is update the values of keys of first `objectArray`, by taking the number of objects with the relevant 'clothType' property in the `userArray`. In this example, the trousers should be assigned 2, 'skirts and jackets' should be assigend 0, and scarfs should be assigned 1.

---

### **Following is the method I tried:**

```
objectArray.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  ...{
    trousers: userArray.filter(d => d.clothType === 'trousers').length,
    'skirts and jackets': userArray.filter(d => d.clothType === 'skirts and jackets').length,
    scarfs: userArray.filter(d => d.clothType === 'scarfs').length,
  },
})),
```

How can I do the above at once, without assigning the values to each key individually?

thank you!

Comment: Will `objectArray` always be of length `1`? What you are asking is not really possible to do at once but you can improve the algorithm and avoid going through `usersArray` three times. Instead, iterate over `usersArray` once and increment the values of each type of cloth by 1 every time you find it

Comment: yes it is always 1

Comment: Then you shouldn't make it an array, it should just be an object. I will add an answer

Comment: I need it as an array for future use. (as an input prop of another package)

Answer (score 0):

Author of the question indicated that `objectArray` is an array with length always 1. With that in mind, here is my suggestion -

Like I said in a comment above, there is no way to do it all at "once", you will have to iterate and count but you can improve the algorithm slightly (Especially, if the `objectArray` doesn't need to be an array because the length is always one)

[Link to full working example in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwILOQQwJ4C55LIAimUmA2gLowC8M5AUDDAN5PMxiYC2i+A5CQBuASwAm-ADTtmwADYgoACwAq2AA58Y-KMhAIUEKTJjrkI4FoAsAVmnMAvvdYmuvAQCkQmMF2McYeUVVDS1+CGBMZAAzI2dmMwstO3YndjYAtzCAcRE5OREffw4g5TVNAV19QjiTRMt8AGYUx2lKBgZQSFhSpUQIAGF9MCh8Xv7y-toXAKqDZAh8AE4ABnjtCABrEWQoCBgfMRgAK0xgTcQ9-nwrAHZ1iKjY-ABGFbXUgG4OmChQwIUygmoX2dAyzDmNXwYDg3AARihvhxwttdvtDiczhcrtDYQjkEjmI8YotOHjEQwHB0mH9NAQUCQyNNwcwsvhoOYwABzQmyQEhCowDkibm80zmBpk+EUqkMeboLDYAB0yEQYjglgAFJr1EJJIEhABKWgAPhmQoA7iIoMAlJrgEIlb1JsaWYFMEgNpESdcTAkhORwt7YvxqABqOgvMXMOGqzCbMWRT0onZ7A5gI6nc6XIy4P2mAMptHpzNYnOhmARmBR-OxxDxxMexDaSGGa4wfO6wOthYVqs1gIxuMJ1LsVVQODIMAF75OAHBfpDOAjQ0dLoQEByRBKhRc+38xfDKCGoA)

```js
const userArray: userData[] = [
  {
    name: 'David',
    clothType: 'trousers',
    price: 45,
  },
  {
    name: 'Joanna',
    clothType: 'scarfs',
    price: 5,
  },
  {
    name: 'Gillian',
    clothType: 'trousers',
    price: 35,
  },
]

const clothesCount: clothesTypes = {
    trousers: 90,
    'skirts and jackets': 47,
    scarfs: 100,
}

userArray.reduce((pv, cv) => {
  switch(cv.clothType) {
    case 'scarfs':
      pv['scarfs'] += 1;
      break;
    case 'skirts and jackets':
      pv['skirts and jackets'] += 1;
      break;
    case 'trousers': 
      pv['trousers'] += 1;
      break;
  }
  return pv;
}, clothesCount)
```

Comment: This solution works if there are limited property in `objectArray`. What if there are hundreds of property in it. That this solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can look over `userArray` and add the count if that property exist in `objectArray` or not.

```js
const objectArray: clothesTypes[] = [{
  trousers: 90,
  'skirts and jackets': 47,
  scarfs: 100,
}, ];

const userArray: userData[] = [{
    name: 'David',
    clothType: 'trousers',
    price: 45,
  },
  {
    name: 'Joanna',
    clothType: 'scarfs',
    price: 5,
  },
  {
    name: 'Gillian',
    clothType: 'trousers',
    price: 35,
  },
];

const objectArrayClone = [...objectArray];
const objectArrayV = objectArrayClone[0];
userArray.forEach((obj) => {
    const { clothType } = obj;
    if (clothType in objectArrayV) {
        objectArrayV[clothType]++;
    }
});

console.log(objectArrayClone);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: 'Property 'clothType' does not exist on type 'clothesTypes' in the `{clothType}` of the statement `const { clothType } = obj;`

Comment: @RitaRangers Can you reproduce this error. May be you can use `codesandbox.io`

Comment: I'm sorry it is due to mistake from my end. but can you make that reassigning of new value to `objectArray` separately. (because it throws an error in redux 'Attempted to reassign readonly  property. I store the objectArray in the redux.) Thank you.

Comment: @RitaRangers You can clone `objectArray`. Updated example